# Making Predictions on single review from input text using saved CNN model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp, sentiment-analysis

I am making a classifier based on a CNN model in Keras.

I will use it in an application, where the user can load the application and enter input text and the model will be loaded from the weights and make predictions.

The thing is I am using GloVe embeddings as well and the CNN model uses padded text sequences as well.

I used Keras tokenizer as following:

```
tokenizer = text.Tokenizer(num_words=max_features, lower=True, char_level=False)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(list(train_x))

train_x = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(train_x)
test_x = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(test_x)

train_x = sequence.pad_sequences(train_x, maxlen=maxlen)
test_x = sequence.pad_sequences(test_x, maxlen=maxlen)
```

I trained the model and predicted on test data, but now I want to test the same with loaded model which I loaded and working.

But my problem here is If I provide a single review, it has to be passed through the `tokeniser.text_to_sequences()` which is returning 2D array, with a shape of `(num_chars, maxlength)` and hence followed by a `num_chars` predictions, but I need it in `(1, max_length)` shape.

I am using the following code for prediction:

```
review = 'well free phone cingular broke stuck not abl offer kind deal number year contract up realli want razr so went look cheapest one could find so went came euro charger small adpat made fit american outlet, gillett fusion power replac cartridg number count packagemay not greatest valu out have agillett fusion power razor'
xtest = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(review)
xtest = sequence.pad_sequences(xtest, maxlen=maxlen)

model.predict(xtest)
```

Output is:

```
array([[0.29289   , 0.36136267, 0.6205081 ],
       [0.362869  , 0.31441122, 0.539749  ],
       [0.32059124, 0.3231736 , 0.5552745 ],
       ...,
       [0.34428033, 0.3363668 , 0.57663095],
       [0.43134686, 0.33979046, 0.48991954],
       [0.22115968, 0.27314988, 0.6188136 ]], dtype=float32)
```

I need a single prediction here `array([0.29289   , 0.36136267, 0.6205081 ])` as I have a single review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you need to pass a list of strings to `texts_to_sequences` method. So you need to put the single review in a list like this:

```
xtest = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([review])
```

If you don't do that (i.e. pass a string, not a list of string(s)), considering the strings in Python are iterable, [it would iterate](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/7b7af2690026b51b5a7a50b4b359ff12960ac8b7/keras_preprocessing/text.py#L297) over the characters of the given string and consider the characters, not words, as the tokens:

```
oov_token_index = self.word_index.get(self.oov_token)
for text in texts:  # <-- it would iterate over the string instead
    if self.char_level or isinstance(text, list):
```

That's why you would get an array of shape `(num_chars, maxlength)` as the return value of `texts_to_sequences` method.