# How to make text-summarizing model predict for a single input?

Tags: python, keras, nlp

So my LSTM-based model takes in a review and summarizes it in a few words. These are the steps I take *on a single input* after cleaning the text:

```
tokenizer = Tokenizer() 
sequence = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([input_string]) 
sequence = pad_sequences(sequences, maxlen = 35)
```

Since `texts_to_sequences` takes in a list of strings, I did `texts_to_sequences([input_string])` after reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53535805/making-predictions-on-single-review-from-input-text-using-saved-cnn-model) to a similar question (and going through [this blogpost](https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/build-spam-classifier-keras-python)). However, I still get an error that `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'`. Looking through the stack trace, it seems that a function called `text_to_word_sequence` in the keras library is being called, and it's taking in a parameter `text` which seems to be a `NoneType` object. How can I fix this issue?

Edit: Here's the full stack trace if it'd be helpful:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "input_to_summary.py", line 55, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1])
  File "input_to_summary.py", line 53, in main
    tokenize_and_predict(processed_text, summarizer)
  File "input_to_summary.py", line 45, in tokenize_and_predict
    sequence = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(np.array([input_string])) 
  File "/projects/32a5c584-399f-4da7-9dc2-6392d0e56d8f/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/text.py", line 279, in texts_to_sequences
    return list(self.texts_to_sequences_generator(texts))
  File "/projects/32a5c584-399f-4da7-9dc2-6392d0e56d8f/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/text.py", line 307, in texts_to_sequences_generator
    seq = text_to_word_sequence(text,
  File "/projects/32a5c584-399f-4da7-9dc2-6392d0e56d8f/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/text.py", line 43, in text_to_word_sequence
    text = text.lower()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Comment: I think you first need to call `tokenizer.fit()` on some text data and then call `tokenizer.texts_to_sequences()`.

Comment: I did `tokenizer.fit_on_texts(input_string)`, and when that didn't work (since the `fit_on_texts` method takes in a list, I did `tokenizer.fit_on_texts([input_string])`, but I still get the same error as above.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I was actually passing in a none-type parameter since the function I used to assign the parameter actually returned nothing!